# Progress of a command running in unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have a very long command running on a very large file. It involves sort, uniq, grep and awk commands in the single command that pipes the results of one command to another.

Once I issue this command for execution, the command prompt doesn't return back until the command has completely executed.

Is there a way to know what is the progress of the command in terms of how much of its execution it has completed or anything similar that gives us an idea of how much of a particular command inside this main command has completed?

Comment: Realistically, no — there isn't an easy way to measure the progress of a command pipeline such as you describe.  The sort is likely the longest running phase; you might be able monitor it somehow via the temporary files it creates, but that isn't a foregone conclusion.  This is a general problem; there isn't a simple way to measure the progress of most commands.

Comment: @Gabe: Can you please provide more insight into what Perl is capable of doing in this context?

Comment: You could use `tail -f` in some other terminal to look at the evolution of some output files.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you're doing I can't say whether or not it would work for you, but have a look at [`pv`](http://code.google.com/p/pipeviewer/).  It might fit the bill.

Answer (score -1):

Perl was originally created because AWK wasn't quite powerful enough for the task at hand. With commands like `sort` and `grep`, and a syntax very similar to AWK's, it should not be hard to translate a command line using those programs into a short Perl script.

The advantage of Perl is that you can easily communicate the progress of your script via `print` statements. For example, you could indicate when the input file was done being loaded, when the sort was completed, etc.

Comment: While I second the evangelisation this isn't an answer to his question.

Comment: @tink: Since this is exactly how I would solve the problem, I think it's as close to an answer as I can write considering that the OP has not given his source.